# how do you deal with localstorage with tests in create react app withour ejecting?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

How can I mock `localstorage` with create react app ?

I am unable to override configuration where I could setup my mocks...

```
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/front/src/setupTests.js"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as described by Facebook:
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests

```
const localStorageMock = {
  getItem: jest.fn(),
  setItem: jest.fn(),
  clear: jest.fn(),
}
global.localStorage = localStorageMock
```

you may use this technique to mock all kind of object that accessible globally.